# Calculating changing Mathf.Clamp() values for object of changing size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been wracking my brain over this problem for a while. I have a controllable object (only moveable up and down) that I have clamped on the top and bottom. However, every time a certain trigger is activated, the object shrinks 10% until it is 90% of the original size. The problem comes in when I shrink it. When it shrinks, the min and max values of the clamp don't change at all and this results in the object clamping to soon on the min and max. They need to decrease and increase respectively so that it clamps in the exact same place. How would one do this? I've tried so many different methods but to no avail...

This is the way I shrink my player:

```
        playerWidth /= 1.1f;
        playerHeight /= 1.1f;

        Vector3 scale = new Vector3(playerWidth, playerHeight, 1f);
        playerOneShrink.transform.localScale = scale;
```

Many Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Let me give an example using  a game that might help get my point across better. Basically think flappy bird, but the player uses the up and down arrows to move and not space-bar. When the bird dies, the bird would reset but become smaller. It seems that because the bird is smaller it now moves 'less' up and down, and doesn't touch the top and bottom of the screen anymore. I want the bird to still be touching the top and bottom of the screen.

**EDIT 2:**

So apparently my first edit didn't clarify as much as I thought so I'm going to show my code for a test scene I'm trying this all in. I haven't shown the changing of minValue and maxValue because that's what I'm struggling with...

```
private static Rigidbody2D playerOneRB;
GameObject player1;
float verticalMovement = 0;

public static float playerHeight = 0.3417f;
public static float playerWidth = 0.05400001f;

public float minValue = 0;
public float maxValue = 10;


public static float p1VerticalSpeed = 3;

public GameObject playerOneShrink;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerOneRB = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("P1 Normal").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    player1= GameObject.Find("P1 Normal");

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    verticalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Player 1 V"); //Looking for axis defined in our input manager
    playerOneRB.velocity = new Vector3(0f, verticalMovement * p1VerticalSpeed, playerOneRB.velocity.x);

    
    Vector3 scale1 = new Vector3(playerWidth, playerHeight, 1f);
    Vector3 position = transform.position;

    player1.transform.position = new Vector3(player1.transform.position.x, (Mathf.Clamp(player1.transform.position.y, minValue, maxValue)), 0f); //Restricting how far the players can move (aka, not off the screen)



    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
        playerWidth /= 1.1f;
        playerHeight /= 1.1f;

        scale1 = new Vector3(playerWidth, playerHeight, 1f);
        paddleOneShrink.transform.localScale = scale1;
    }
}
```

Here's a photo of what's happening:

[1. Photo of position it reaches before shrinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewd7e.png)

[2. Photo of position it reaches after shrinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekvZb.png)

I want the player in image 2 to be able to get to the same top position as in image 1 after it shrinks.

Comment: Your edit seems to make the question more confusing... can we see the code where you are calling the clamp()?

Comment: @Jake I added more info if you'd like to take a look! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood your problem.

So let's assume the scale of the player is 1 unit and you have to clamp in y axis between 0 and 10.

so you will have to clamp the Y position of player like

```
   Vector3 scale = new Vector3(playerWidth, playerHeight, 1f);
   Vector3 position = transform.position;
   position.y =  mathf.clamp(0 + scale.x ,10 - scale.x ,position.y ); 
   transform.position = position;
```

so if the player's scale is 1 then it will limit the y position between 1 (0+1) and 9 (10-1).

if the player's scale is 0.9 then it will be between 0.9 (0+0.9 ) and 9.1 (10-0.9)

if the scale is 3 then between 3 (0+3) and 7 (10-3)

Comment: THANK YOU! All I had to do was change it to scale.y and that seemed to fix my problems perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to scale the object, but keep it pivoted, so if it's at the top most position, and scales, it stays at the top most position? If so, the code and answers here will help:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/14170/scaling-an-object-from-a-different-center.html

You'll of course need to add in some conditional code to check whether it's a top or bottom pivot.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking to achieve. I might be misunderstanding, but let me just try explain using a game that might help get my point across better. Basically think flappy bird, but the player uses the up and down arrows to move and not space-bar. When the bird dies, the bird would reset but become smaller. It seems that because the bird is smaller it now moves 'less' up and down, and doesn't touch the top and bottom of the screen anymore. Am I correct that what you're mentioning wouldn't solve this?